# Android - Making a snapping Horizontal ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, horizontal-scrolling

How can I make a horizontal list view in android that snaps? What I mean by snaps is that it acts like a Pager, but I can use an adapter for the list with 
`mList.setAdapter(adapter);`.

I have tried libraries but none of them work because I am working with Android Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with using a ViewPager?

Comment: @Karakuri how can I adapt a List<> to a ViewPager?

Comment: Using a `PagerAdapter`

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm new to Android and Java and didn't know about that. Thanks